# How to include apache cxf plugin inside build.gradle (spring boot )?

Tags: java, wsdl, build.gradle, cxf

I have **pom.xml** file which is absolutely working fine with the given **apache cxf codegen plugin** in **MAVEN**.But I need to create my project in gradle so I need the same plugin in **build.gradle** to generate classes.

This is what I have tried.. My build.gradle file looks like this

```
configurations {
    jaxb
}

task genJaxb {
    ext.sourcesDir = "src/main/generated-sources/jaxb"
    ext.classesDir = "src/main/classes/jaxb"
    ext.schema = "../app-webapp/src/main/resources/xyz.wsdl"//my wsdl file location in my project

    outputs.dir classesDir

    doLast() {
        project.ant {
            taskdef name: "xjc", classname: "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath
            mkdir(dir: sourcesDir)
            mkdir(dir: classesDir)

            xjc(destdir: sourcesDir, schema: schema,
                    package: "com.model") {
                arg(value: "-wsdl")
                produces(dir: sourcesDir, includes: "**/*.java")
            }

            javac(destdir: classesDir, source: 1.8, target: 1.8, debug: true,
                    debugLevel: "lines,vars,source",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath) {
                src(path: sourcesDir)
                include(name: "**/*.java")
                include(name: "*.java")
            }

            copy(todir: classesDir) {
                fileset(dir: sourcesDir, erroronmissingdir: false) {
                    exclude(name: "**/*.java")
                }
            }
        }
    }

dependencies {

  compile(files(genJaxb.classesDir).builtBy(genJaxb))

    jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.3.2'
    jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1'
    jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.2'

    compile project(':app-model')
    compile project(':app-repository')
    compile project(':app-service')
}
```

After trying this.. I can see the generated classes but not **Service 
endpoint Interface** which has to be there (the one which consists of 
@webservice annotation). But with maven everything is getting 
generated...
instead of Jaxb can I use cxf?

This is my Pom.xml

```
    <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generate-sources</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <sourceRoot>src/main/java-generated</sourceRoot>
                                <wsdlOptions>
                                    <wsdlOption>
                                        <wsdl>src/main/resources/xyz.wsdl</wsdl>
                                        <extraargs>
                                            <extraarg>-frontend</extraarg>
                                            <extraarg>jaxws21</extraarg>
                                            <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                        </extraargs>
                                        <bindingFiles>
                                            <bindingFile>src/main/resources/jaxws-binding.xml
                             </bindingFile>
                                        </bindingFiles>
                                    </wsdlOption>
                                </wsdlOptions>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

I expect same plugin in build.gradle file which should generate all the classes including **Service Endpoint Interface**

Comment: Did you get this under control? I face a similar issue. Having three Apache CXF dependencies in my pom.,xml, everything works as expected. Now I migrate to Gradle, put the same three dependencies into the build script - and there are a lot of differences and e.g. WebService is missing completely. What is CXF doing there? Why don't the Gradle dependencies work just like in Maven?